# TF: Model SubClassing | AttributionError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'compile'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to implement sub-classing for model definition in `tf.keras` in following way and facing following attribution error.

```py
def my_model(Model):
    def __init__(self, dim):
        super(my_model, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.efnet  = efn.EfficientNetB0(input_shape=(dim, 3), include_top = False, weights = 'imagenet')
        self.gap    = L.GlobalAveragePooling2D()
        self.bn     = L.BatchNormalization()
        self.denseA = L.Dense(784, activation='relu', name = 'dense_A')
        self.out    = L.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
    
    def call(self, inputs):
        x     = self.efnet(inputs)
        x_gap = self.gap(x)
        bn    = self.bn(x_gap)
        den_A = self.denseA(bn)
        drop  = self.drop(den_A)
        return self.out(drop)

dim = (124,124)
model = my_model((dim)
```

#### Error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-e8086e70a144> in <module>()
     27 dim = (124,124)
     28 model = my_model(dim)
---> 29 model.compile(
     30     optimizer='adam',
     31     loss = 'binary_crossentropy',

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'compile'
```

**Environment**

```
OS: Windows OS
TF Ver. tf 2.1
```

**Reproducibility**
Here is the reproducible code in [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/ravikyram/f8f3165fa91902706788d3a040f3bf98/untitled869.ipynb).

---

#### TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be **class** not **function**.

Instead of `def my_model(Model):` , it should be `class my_model(Model):` . And also we need to `build` the model further. Here is the full code:

```py
class my_model(Model):
    def __init__(self, dim):
        super(my_model, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.efnet  = efn.EfficientNetB0(input_shape=(dim, 3), include_top = False, weights = 'imagenet')
        self.gap    = L.GlobalAveragePooling2D()
        self.bn     = L.BatchNormalization()
        self.denseA = L.Dense(784, activation='relu', name = 'dense_A')
        self.out    = L.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
    
    def call(self, inputs):
        x     = self.efnet(inputs)
        x_gap = self.gap(x)
        bn    = self.bn(x_gap)
        den_A = self.denseA(bn)
        drop  = self.drop(den_A)
        return self.out(drop)

dim = (124,124)
model = my_model((dim)
model.build((None, *dim))
model.compile(...)
model.summary()
```